# How to exchange the width and height of the preview size in android camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

We can open android camera by the specify preview size, such as:

```
mParameter.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
mCamera.setParameter(mParameter);
```

The ratio above is 1.3333333333333333

Is there any way to exchange the width and height? That is to say the effect like this:

```
mParameter.setPreviewSize(480, 640);
mCamera.setParameter(mParameter);
```

The ratio is 0.75

Comment: While you are certainly welcome to call `setPreviewSize()` as you have there, expect many devices to crash, saying that this is not a supported preview size.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes. It will be crashed in many devices. SO is there any way to implement the effect same as the second one?

Comment: You could try using a `TextureView` for your preview surface and applying a matrix to the `TextureView` to rotate the preview frames.

Answer (score 0):

All the video preview sizes are not support in all devices. You can only do it programmatically. **If the size is not applicable then throw the media recorder stop -19 error**

```
int width = 320;
            int height = 240;
            try {
                //get the available sizes of the video
                List<Size> tmpList = getSupportedVideoSizes();

                final List<Size> sizeList = new Vector<Size>();

                // compare the apsect ratio of the candidate sizes against the
                // real ratio
                Double aspectRatio = (Double.valueOf(getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()) / getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
                for (int i = tmpList.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    Double tmpRatio = Double.valueOf(tmpList.get(i).height)
                            / tmpList.get(i).width;
                    if (EnableLog.LOG_TAG) {
                        Log.e("Width & height", tmpList.get(i).width + " x "
                                + tmpList.get(i).height);
                    }
                    if (Math.abs(aspectRatio - tmpRatio) < .15) {
                        width = tmpList.get(i).width;
                        height = tmpList.get(i).height;
                        sizeList.add(tmpList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                if (EnableLog.LOG_TAG) {
                    Log.e("tmpList", tmpList + "*");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // set the size of video.
            // If the size is not applicable then throw the media recorder stop
            // -19 error
            mrec.setVideoSize(width, height);

/**
     * This method will return the size of the video
     * 
     * if the getSupportedVideoSizes() is return null
     * 
     * then it is possible to get the size of video from
     * getSupportedPreviewSizes()
     * 
     * @return list of size
     */
    public List<Size> getSupportedVideoSizes() {
            if (params.getSupportedVideoSizes() != null) {
                return params.getSupportedVideoSizes();
            } else {
                // Video sizes may be null, which indicates that all the supported
                // preview sizes are supported for video recording.
                return params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            }
        }
```

Try this code maybe it will help.

**EDIT:**

As per your comment you want to set the best preview size so you need to change the for loop. i will show you the example

change this for loop

```
for (int i = tmpList.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < tmpList.size()-1; i++) {
}
```

This will give you the better preview size.

Comment: No. I am not to find a way that match the best preview size, but implement the effect after exchanging the width and height.

Comment: This code will set the lowest preview size you need to change the for loop for best preview size. i will update my question. Check my edit.